# SQL JOIN : Technical name for table identifier

Tags: sql, nomenclature

When I use A.column name, B.Column name where A = Table A and B = Table B , what is the technical name for the A.Column name? Is it a prefix, identifier or what else?

Answer (score 9):

I have always seen it called an alias.

Edit:
[Yeap!](http://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_alias.asp)

Answer (score 2):

They also call it a "Correlation Name"

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r1/ic2924/index.htm?info/db2/rbafzmstc2cornm.htm

Answer (score 1):

I think `correlation` name is properly the alias used in a `correlated subquery`.
In the query below **E2** is the `correlation` name.

```
SELECT  EMPNO, LASTNAME, WORKDEPT, EDLEVEL
FROM    EMPLOYEE
WHERE   EDLEVEL >
        (SELECT AVG(E2.EDLEVEL)
        FROM    EMPLOYEE **E2**
        WHERE   E2.WORKDEPT = WORKDEPT
        )
```

Comment: That's not correct.  The term correlation name is used whether or not you have a correlated subquery.

Answer (score 1):

From my copy of "SQL-99 Complete, Really":

> A `<Correlation name>` (or alias)
>   identifies a variable that ranges over
>   some Table; that is, a variable whose
>   only permitted values are the rows of
>   a given Table.

So either "alias" or "correlation name" is acceptable.  Though "alias" is also used for column aliases defined in the select-list, so if you use this term you should be clear about which one you mean.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct name is table-alias